# How to avoid "message superview sent to freed object" iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have this code:

```
 CardView *aCardView = [self prendiCartaDalMazzo];

 [aCardView removeFromSuperview]; 
 [self.mieCarte addSubview:aCardView];
```

when i try to add aCardView as as subview of mieCarte then i get this error:

> objc[4800]: FREED(id): message superview sent to freed object=0x393f130
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.

Thanks at all can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-removeFromSuperview does a release, which probably causes destruction (the superview's reference is probably the last remaining one)..

Do

```
[aCardView retain];
[aCardView removeFromSuperview];
```

...

instead.

Comment: i thougth that having a pointer to an instance of aCardView that was enalf thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`removeFromSuperview` also releases the receiver (just as `addSubview:` retains it).

You need to retain the card view before removing it and then release it again after adding it as a subview to another view.